# VB.net Suggestions for SMTP client connection error, trying to send message through exchange server

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server, smtpclient

So I'm trying to connect to our exchange server and send a message through vb.net using the smtpClient.  Here is my code:

```
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("exchangeserver.com")
    Dim mail As New MailMessage
    mail.From = New MailAddress("me@me.com")
    mail.To.Add("me@me.com")
    mail.Subject = "Test Email"
    mail.Body = "Testing body."
    Try
        smtp.Send(mail)
    Catch exc As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString)
    End Try
```

The exception I'm getting indicates that:

```
 System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure Sending mail. --->
 System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions ##.##.#.##:25
```

Seems like I can't connect on that port?  No permissions... should I try something else or revert back to sending emails through outlook?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" while using SMTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779336/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permiss)

Answer (score 1):

one thing to check... you may need to set credentials... look into this

```
smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential( "blah blah blah", "yada yada")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no dice.  I still got the same error after inserting my credentials.  I'm reviewing a few other possibilities.