# Error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c#, console-application, smtpclient

I'm trying to send an email from a C# console application but am seeing this error:

> {"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions xx.xxx.xx.xxx:25"}

What's weird is that I have another MVC 5 application that uses the exact same code other than specifying a different subject and body and it works fine. Why would one work on my machine and the other fail?

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("noreply@server.com", "Testing Email");
MailMessage email = new MailMessage(from, new MailAddress("me@server.com")); 
email.Subject = "Errors For " + DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString();
email.Body = body;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.server.com");
client.Send(email);
```

I am not using SSL so the suggested duplicate doesn't apply. Also, it does work for another C# running on the same PC for the same user through the same smtp server.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" while using SMTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779336/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permiss)

Comment: I may be missing something, but both projects are using port 25. Why would it work for one and not the other?

Comment: Are both projects being executed on the same PC? Under the same user account? Using the same SMTP server? Fact is, there really is not enough detail in your question to offer an answer. You will get much better, much faster information by simply doing a search (Stack Overflow or web) on the error message text.

Comment: So, yes (same PC), yes (same user account), yes (same SMTP server). I guess I'm hoping that someone would know what differences there could be between a console app and a MVC app that might cause a difference like this.

Comment: i guess you are running in a limited code execution mode of c# (partial trust) that wont let you open sockets

Comment: Is it running elevated (as administrator) on the working machine?

Comment: Well, your two projects have similar code. But code alone doesn't necessarily give a complete picture. What about configuration, for example? Could there be differences with the mail / proxy / network / security settings in your two projects' App.config files?

Comment: @pm100 I tried opening the project's properties and going to the security tab. I selected the one click security and set it to full trust but it still hit the problem.

Comment: @stakx I think you're on to something that's kind of why I'm asking. I tried checking those and there's no setting that jumps out at me. Thanks

Comment: @griztown - Do you have an appxmanifest file? Check to see if [access over Private Networks is enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20623477/951830)