# cannot connect to private server, socketerror - accessdenied

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

i'm trying to connect to our private company server. I'm connected through VPN to company network. Here is snippet of code:

```
static ManualResetEvent _clientDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var host = new DnsEndPoint("XX.XXXX.com", port, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        args.RemoteEndPoint = host;
        args.Completed += Args_Completed;

        _clientDone.Reset();
        socket.ConnectAsync(args);

        _clientDone.WaitOne(5000);

        var listener = new StreamSocketListener();


    }

    private string result;
    private void Args_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        result = e.SocketError.ToString();
        _clientDone.Set();
    }
```

SocketError returns AccessDenied. If I try another address, SocketError is Success. I've checked capabilities: Internet (Client)/(Client & Server), Private networks. But it doesn't work.

> ConnectByNameError = {"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"}

I did the same connection in Console App and result was success.

So why the result is AccessDenied in UWP?
Thanks for help

**EDIT:**
I'm connected using CISCO VPN. But now I've tried to run the code in mobile emulator and result is Success. On Local Machine is accessdenied.

Comment: Tested your code, it works fine on local machine, is it possible your port on the local machine is already used by a socket connection?

Answer (score 1):

Check the firewall on the local machine, it might be blocking it silently?
As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799651/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi) user had issues with?

Comment: I turned off ESET firewall, but still the same issue. I can't explain myself, why it is working on mobile emulator, but not on Local Machine.

Comment: And I completely turned off windows firewall. Still the same problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779336/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permiss