# Attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, email, smtp

I'm using smtp google's server to send a email through my contact form..In local server it works fine but in web server it shows this error.First ,I've used port number **587** which gives error "Security Exception" and error was on the line `using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))`, but I've changed port to **25** and it gives this new error on the line .

```
smtp.Send(mail);
```

**Description**:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 74.125.206.108:25

My code is:

```
protected void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
    int portNumber = 25;
    bool enableSSL = true;

    string emailfrom = "isl@gmail.com";
    string password = "******";
    string subject = "Contact Form Data";
    string emailto = "isl@gmail.com";
    string name = n.Value;       
    string useremail = em.Value;
    string phone = tel.Value;
    string dept = dep.Value;
    string dest = des.Value;
    string adu = ad.Value;

    string msg = mes.Value;
    string body = "Name: " + name + " ;" + " Email: " + useremail + " ;" + "Telephone: " + phone + " ;" + " Departure Place: " + dept + " ;" + "Destination Place: " + dest + " ;" + " Adults: " + adu + " ;" + " ;" + "Children: " + chil + " ;" + "Message: " + msg + " ;";

    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress(emailfrom);
        mail.To.Add(emailto);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
        {
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailfrom, password);
            smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

> [SocketException (0x271d): An attempt was made to access a socket in a
>   way          forbidden by its access permissions 74.125.206.108:25]
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) +208
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception) +464
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream,
>   Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket,
>   Socket& abortSocket6) +6662436 System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +307
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +19
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, 
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) +324
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint) +141
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
>   +170 System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() +44 System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1554
>
> [SmtpException: Failure sending mail.] 
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1906
>   Contact.send_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   \smb-whst-www02\whst_www02$\ff8b1b\user\medviewair.uk\web\Contact.aspx.cs:51
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628462
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +103 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779336/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permiss)?

Comment: If it works locally but not on the web server, check the firewall on the web server to make sure outbound connections on your chosen port are allowed. Try to connect from the web server to your smtp server using `telnet` over your chosen port. Also, have you tried connecting using port 465?  Or try port 25 with  `smtp.EnableSsl = false;`

Comment: I've tried different port numbers and enablessL to false but it still doesn't work..

Comment: Have you verified the web server is allowing outbound connections over that port?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799651/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissi)

Answer (score 24):

After Windows Update, some ports are reserved by Windows and applications **cannot bind to these ports**. please check this command

netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp

Comment: This was my problem (other usecase however). Now up for a solution to free the port for me...

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/1579346/many-excludedportranges-how-to-delete-hyper-v-is-disabled       netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=9999(your port) numberofports=1

Answer (score 4):

Kindly check that your web server is properly configured and it is up and running.

In case, if your application is throwing an exception then follow the below steps

1. Go to "Start" --> "Control Panel"
2. Click on "Windows Firewall"
   [image]
3. Inside Windows Firewall, click on "Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall"
   [image]
4. Now inside of Allow Programs, Click on "Change Settings" button. Once you clicked on  Change Settings button, the "Allow another program..." button gets enabled.
   [image]
5. Click on "Allow another program..." button , a new dialog box will be opened. Choose the programs or application for which you are getting the socket exception and click on "Add"
   [image]
6. Click OK, and restart your machine.
7. Try to run your application (which earlier had an exception) with administrative rights.

I hope this helps.

Peace,

Sunny Makode

Answer (score 1):

I have disabled McAfee and it worked, certainly its firewall or Antivirus settings

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable Kaspersky End Point Security anti-virus

Answer (score 0):

Could the port already be in *exclusive* use?  Use NirSoft's 'CPorts' utility to check if it is or not.

Comment: plz upload full description of your problem