# Email not being sent when Button click event C#/ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am working within a domain and we use an virtual machine SMTP server acting as a relay. What I am trying to do is send an email to myself from myself through this virtual SMTP server. I have allowed my computer's IP address to relay emails through the server and have added it to my code. The server doesn't need/have credentials to relay email traffic. Below is my code and a picture to show that I allowed it through the relay. Any help would be much appreciated.
The error I am getting is:

I finally just applied it to the server thinking for some reason it was just my computer not allowing it. Then I get a different error which is as followed:

New Error Message:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: '***IP of the SMTP Server***'

Old Error Message below:

> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions (***IP of the SMTP Server***)
>   Source Error:Line 30: 
>   Line 31:             //smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
>   Line 32:             smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
>   Line 33: 
>   Line 34:

Below is my code:

asp.net bit:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Button was clicked" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

C# Code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("emailaddress@mail.mil", "emailaddress@mail.mil");
            mailMessage.Subject = "Hello";
            mailMessage.Body = "This works";

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("serverName", 25);
            //SmtpClient smtpcClient = new SmtpClient("serverName", 25);

            //smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Picture of the VM allowing my computer access to send the email.:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5N8z.png

Comment: The access may be restricted by network firewall or on the server

Comment: Take a look also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779336/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permiss