# Getting Error While Sending Mail From ASP.net Website while working through Windows Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, smtp

Wwhile I am trying to send mail using smtp client I am getting the following exception.

However I am able to send mail using same settings through Windows Application.

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a
> socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:25
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
> SocketAddress s`enter code here`ocketAddress)at
> System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
> Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
> ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
> exception)

this Is my code

public static void SendEmail(string strBody, string strSubject, string strTo, string strCC, string strBcc, string filepath)
{

```
        try
        {
            AppCommon.AppConstant.WriteLogFile("sending mail to "+ strTo);
            AppSettingsReader g = new AppSettingsReader();
            string fromadd = "";
            fromadd = (string)g.GetValue("SMTPFromAddress", typeof(string));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromadd))
                fromadd = "abc@mydomain.com";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTo))
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress(fromadd);

                foreach (string toEmail in strTo.Split(','))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(toEmail))
                        mail.To.Add(toEmail);
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCC))
                    mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(strCC));
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strBcc))
                    mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(strBcc));

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Host = (string)g.GetValue("SMTPHost", typeof(string));
                client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(g.GetValue("SMTPPort", typeof(Int32)));
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.EnableSsl = false;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential((string)g.GetValue("SMTPUserName", typeof(string)), (string)g.GetValue("SMTPPassword", typeof(string)));
                

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
                {
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
                    {
                        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(filepath);
                        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    }
                }

                mail.Subject = strSubject;
                mail.Body = strBody;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                client.Send(mail);
                Console.WriteLine("Email sent.");

                if (mail.Attachments != null)
                {
                    for (Int32 i = mail.Attachments.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        mail.Attachments[i].Dispose();
                    }
                    mail.Attachments.Clear();
                    mail.Attachments.Dispose();
                }
                mail.Dispose();
                mail = null;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            AppCommon.AppConstant.WriteLogFile(Convert.ToString(ex.InnerException));
        }
    }
```

Comment: show the code so we know exactly how you connect in both cases, please. Also, are you running both applications from the same machine, or does the asp.net run on a different server? It could be that the server has outbound connection restrictions imposed. Or is anything else trying to use that port on the outbound machine already, perhaps? Lots of useful advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779336/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permiss ...did you research or try anything yourself yet?

Comment: You tagged this as `sendmail` which is a Unix mail program. Removed tag.

Comment: Code is added Same Code is Used from Same Machine